# Bootstrap container spacing

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I created a bootstrap HTML site and converted it to wordpress. I put a shadow in all of the **.container** to make it uniform here is my **.container** css

```
.container{
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;
-moz-box-shadow:
     5px 0 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5),
     -5px 0 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
-webkit-box-shadow:
    5px 0 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5),
   -5px 0 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
box-shadow:
    5px 0 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5),
    -5px 0 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

the result what I got is 
[image]
I want to have a result where in the shadow is continuous and no space in between.
here is the fiddle preview of what I have done so far

[jsfiddle.net/2KpQ3](http://jsfiddle.net/2KpQ3)

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the value of your `box-shadow` property. For example:

```
.container{
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
   -moz-box-shadow:
         5px 0 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5),
         -5px 0 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        5px 0 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5),
       -5px 0 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow:
        5px 0 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5),
        -5px 0 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```